# How to Delete File using Form?

Tags: php, laravel, octobercms

I'm using OctoberCMS, based on Laravel.

I'm trying to delete a file. I enter the filename in a text box and press submit.

**Component Form**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ url('/purge') }}">
    <input type="hidden" name="_handler" value="onPurge" />
    {{ form_token() }}
    {{ form_sessionKey() }}

    <input type="text" name="filename" /> 

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Purge" />  
</form>
```

**Component PHP**

```
public function onPurge(){
    $name = $_POST['filename'];

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file->delete(storage_path("app/media/$name"));
    }
}
```

Error

```
Non-static method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model::delete() should not be called statically
```

I tried

```
public function onPurge(){
    $name = $_POST['filename'];

    if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
        $file = new Video();
        $file->delete(storage_path("app/media/$name"));
    }
}
```

(also with full path /var/www/mysite/public/)

The function completes, No error, but the file does not delete.

Comment: As a debugging concern I recommend you to first check if you are getting file if exists with File::exists() if exists you can right your own code as is. P.S. change your path to absolute $path = public_path()."/storage/app/media/" something like this or check path of file too.

Comment: @rahul_m I adjusted my code path. File does not delete but I got return true with: if (File::exists(storage_path("app/media/$name"))) { echo "File Exists"; }

Comment: good pass File::delete(storage_path("app/media/$name"))); and try once

Comment: and write legal code like this, if exists then only delete the file else skip the portion

Comment: Try like \File::exists and same for \File::delete

Comment: @rahul_m Correction, it is echoing that the file exists even if I put the wrong file name. If I call File::delete without using $file->delete, I get error "Non-static method should not be called statically".

Comment: Try like \File::exists and same for \File::delete I gave you sample code in my answer once give that a try.

Comment: @rahul_m The slash worked, it now deletes. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your purge function should be like,

```
public function onPurge(){
    $name = $_POST['filename'];
    $file_path = storage_path("app/media/$name");
    if(File::exists($file_path)){ // OR \File::exists($file_path)
     File::delete($file_path); // OR \File::delete($file_path)
    }
}
```

I feel it should work.

Give it a try.

Comment: Please don't recommend access directly to `$_POST` super globals it's makes hard to test it

Comment: I know mate, I would rather suggest $request variable inside every controller method. But I considered feasibility of OP

Answer (score 1):

You can use the php function unlink instead.

```
if (!empty($_POST['submit'])) {
    $removed = unlink($path . $file);
}if(!$removed) {
   die('file could not be deleted');
}
```

Comment: I get the error Call to undefined method October\Rain\Database\QueryBuilder::unlink()